# Test my react(button) component, mock function received 0 calls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Below is my script:

```
export interface InputProps {
    value: string;
    onSubmit: (value: string) => void;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

const InputBox: React.FC<InputProps> = (props: InputProps) => {
    return (
        <InputWrapper>
            <InputField
                value={props.value}
                onSubmit={() => {
                    props.onSubmit;
                    console.log('onsubmit function is being called.');
                }}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                button={true}
            />
        </InputWrapper>
    );
};
```

Below is my test:

```
describe('<InputBox />', () => {
    const onSubmitMock = jest.fn();
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();

const Test = <InputBox onSubmit={onSubmitMock} onChange={onChangeMock} value="test" />;

it('called onSubmitMock when click submit', () => {
    const { getAllByRole } = render(Test);
    fireEvent.click(getAllByRole('button'));
    expect(onSubmitMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but it gives me error:     Number of calls: 0

However, my onChange test is passed:

```
it('called onChangeMock when click submit', () => {
    const { getAllByRole } = render(Test);
    fireEvent.click(getAllByRole('button'));
    expect(onChangeMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The only difference b/t onChange and onSubmit is I have an arrow function for the onSubmit property.

Question one, why can't I call the onSubmitMock like the onChangeMock?

Question two (deleted)

Any idea of this? Huge thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question one, why can't I call the onSubmitMock like the onChangeMock?

For a function to get called, someone must call it. If you write the code `props.onChange` with no parentheses, then you are just referencing a function, not calling it. So with both `props.onSubmit;` and `onChange={props.onChange}`, the function will not get called. Not on this line of code anyway...

But the `onChange` prop is designed so that if you pass a reference of a function into it, then react guarantees that it will call the function for you, if and when the change event happens. So later on when the event happens, react calls `props.onChange` for you.

With the `onSubmit` function, you've also passed a function into it: the anonymous arrow function you wrote, who's text is:

```
() => {
  props.onSubmit;
  console.log('onsubmit function is being called.');
}
```

When the event happens, react will call that function. Inside your custom function you can do whatever you like, including calling props.onSubmit. But you will be calling it yourself, not asking react (or anything else) to call it for you, so to call it yourself you need `props.onSubmit()`

> Question two [...]

It's not clear to me what code you had that was causing the type error. If you show the code that caused the error, i'll edit this question to answer that

Comment: For my original question two. You can ignored it now.. it seems like even though I make a function for it. It still can't invoke the onSubmitHandler in jest. (I update it on the post)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to call the `onSubmit` callback function. Just add the missing parenthesis like this:

```
  onSubmit={() => {
    props.onSubmit();
  }}
```

If the `console.log` is not needed, then this should work:

```
  onSubmit={props.onSubmit}
```